# tamaño de tiket dinamico en app genexus

Tags: genexus, app

Buenas tengo un app/genexus/java
en la app genero un tiket que quiero lograr que el tamaño del tiket sea de acuerdo
a lo que contiene el documento.
Ejemplo:
Si va a imprimir 500 lineas, que el tiket se ajuste a eso, y no me quede corto o largo la
hoja

/*NO SE SI ES POSIBLE LLEGAR A HACER ESO*/

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que tiene el ticket? ¿Una imagen? ¿Un att. char/long var char? ¿Qué es lo que lo hace dinámico?

Comment: es el tiket que te dan en los supermercados al realizar el pago, es ese mismo.
son distintas variables que estan en el procedimiento

Comment: Por ejemplo solo tenes un producto en lista, pero el tiket te sale de igual tamaño para todos(15 cm). en caso de que pase el tamaño del tiket lo doblega (30 cm)

Comment: @GuidoLorenzatti